# How do I merge data from one row to another by keeping some column values unchanged in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are few rows in the DataFrame and these are the columns 'Product', 'Category', 'Size', 'Rating', 'Reviews' and 'Price'.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
  Product    Category       Size      Rating      Reviews       Price
1  'A'       Kids_1         small       4           10           100
2  'B'       Adults         Medium      3           15           200
3  'C'       Kids_1         Medium      3           15           125
4  'A'       Kids_1         small       4           25           100
5  'D'       Adults         Large       2           10           250
6  'A'       Kids_1         Medium      4           10           100
```

I want to merge the common values in the 'Category' column  and take the highest value in the 'Reviews' column, by merging the values from the rows. On the "Size" column  "Kids_1" category there are small and medium size's to which it should be actually small size based on the product "A".

I tried using groupby function, but couldn't get the output DataFrame as required resulting DataFrame. Instead I got the output as below,

```
                               Rating      Reviews       Price 
  Product  Category    Size
1  'A'      Kids_1     small     4           25           100
2                      Medium    4           10           100
3  'B'      Adults     Medium    3           15           200
4  'C'      Kids_1     Medium    3           15           125
5  'D'      Adults     Large     2           10           250
```

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
  Product    Category      size      Rating      Reviews       Price
1  'A'       Kids_1       small       4           25           100
2  'B'       Adults       Medium      3           15           200
3  'C'       Kids_1       Medium      3           15           125
4  'D'       Adults       Large       2           10           250
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order the dataframe using `Reviews`, group by product and category, and select the top row in each group using `head(1)`.

```
df.sort_values('Reviews', ascending=False).groupby(['Product','Category']).head(1).reset_index(drop=True)
  Product Category    Size  Rating  Reviews  Price
0     'A'   Kids_1   small       4       25    100
1     'B'   Adults  Medium       3       15    200
2     'C'   Kids_1  Medium       3       15    125
3     'D'   Adults   Large       2       10    250
```